Gazebo Foundation
I have a concrete slab that is 2.5" thick. I would like to build a gazebo/arbor to hang porch swings from and would likely just use a shade sail for the top. I would be using 6x6's for both posts and beams. The setup would be similar to the image except ours would be 20' x 10' with a post in the middle of the 20' section and supports inside the corners.

I already have the post bases that are in the image and would like to use them. Would this work with the 2.5" concrete slab? If not, what would be the best way to strengthen up the parts of the slab where the posts would sit.

Is there any issue at all in leaving the from 20' beam off? So it would just be 3 sided.




with 2.5 inch concrete to screw in, it will at best hold it self, but not the porch swings

Concrete is not that hard/structural if on the thin side.  Maybe cut out a 2ftx2ft or 3ftx3ft from the slab where the posts go.  remove the concrete and dig down a few extra inches.  4 to 6 inch thick footings for the posts should act better for anchor points.  Concrete saws can be rented.  It is the swing movement that is the problem.

we don't know the mix of the concrete or if it is reinforced, or poured on firm ground, so any answer would be a guess.  If I was faced with the same unknowns, I would cut out the areas where the supports go and pour deeper footings. 12" x 12" by 10" deep would be my choice.
